# Optional class in Android

Tags: java, android, option-type, throwable

I try to compile this code in android studio:

```
public class Test {
    public void test() {
        java.util.Optional.of(12).orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new);
    }
}
```

It requires to handle Throwable.

But signature of this method is next:

```
public <X extends Throwable> T orElseThrow(Supplier<? extends X> exceptionSupplier) throws X
```

I extract Optional.class from android.jar in Android/Sdk/platforms/android-27 and decompile it with android studio. It has wrong signature:

```
public <X extends Throwable> T orElseThrow(Supplier<? extends X> exceptionSupplier) throws Throwable
```

What I do wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: What is your problem? That you have to handle exception using this code?

Comment: Problem that this code requires to handle Throwable (catch or declare 'throws'). But I throw runtime exception and it must compiles without any changes.

Comment: Try using com.annimon.stream.Optional instead

Comment: I use streams in my project and their return java.util.Optional

Comment: Could you live with using the no-arg `orElseThrow`? It throws a `NoSuchElementException`, a subclass of `RuntimeException`, so doesn’t require you to catch or declare. Im case your API level is not high enough, the `get` method provides the same functionality.

Comment: I try to copypaste source class Optional to my project and use it for my example. This works well. I don't know why android sdk provides Optional.class with wrong signature.

Comment: Is this the same class that you're referring to https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow(java.util.function.Supplier%3C?%20extends%20X%3E) ?

Comment: Yes it's the same: android studio has option 'download sources'.

Comment: @MichaelOrlov You've definitely mixed up something here `public <X extends Throwable> T orElseThrow(Supplier<? extends X> exceptionSupplier) throws Throwable
` wouldn't even compile if you notice the standalone `T` there. Maybe an incorrect jar?

Comment: @nullpointer it's compiled. It makes me think that this Optional.class compiled from another source file :)  android.jar downloads from android studio automatically. I tried to re-download it, but it doesn't affect.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use `java.util.Optional` try this way:

```
if(!java.util.Optional.of(12).isPresent()){
     throw new RuntimeException();
}
```

Comment: It's bad, because I have too many places when I need this construction. Creating method for this is bad too because we lose readability if stream chain is so large.